# Problem with multiprocessing in selenium for loop

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

## Original question

I'm trying to scrap data from a table (1000rows). Here is my code:

```py
@func_timer
def get_data():
    form = driver.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "tr")

    form_data = []
    for row in form[1:-1]:
        row_text = row.text
        link, *_, expire, price, _, _ = row_text.split(" ")
        href = row.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "a_ym").get_attribute('href')
        form_data.append((link, expire, price, href))
    return form_data
```

My code is working properly, but this for loop is very slow (it takes 60~70 seconds). How can I make this for loop faster?

## First update

I think my problem could be solved with multiprocessing, and here is some of my new code and research I did.

```py
def get_row_data(row):
    row_text = row.text
    link, *_, expire, price, _, _ = row_text.split(" ")
    href = row.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,"a_ym").get_attribute('href')
    return link, expire, price, href


def get_data():
    form = driver.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "tr")
    with multiprocessing.Pool() as pool:
        form_data = pool.map(get_row_data, form[1:-1])
    return form_data
```

But I got the following error:
`AttributeError: Can't pickle local object '_createenviron.<locals>.encode'`

Comment: Can you share the full code? I'm quite sure I can speed up a lot the code in the original question from 60 seconds to 6